# send2trash module ValueError

Tags: python

I am trying to use the send2trash module in python to follow along with 'Automate The Boring Stuff,' but I keep getting the following error:

```
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import send2trash
>>> send2trash.send2trash(r"C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\tMorph\tMorph.dll")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    send2trash.send2trash(r"C:\Users\myusernamehere\Desktop\tMorph\tMorph.dll")
  File "C:\Users\myusernamehere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\send2trash\plat_win.py", line 49, in send2trash
    fileop.pFrom = LPCWSTR(path + '\0')
ValueError: embedded null character
```

I have tried multiple files in different locations, but I still get the exact same error.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you are required to use Python 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to send2trash version 1.4.2 fixed the issue for me

Comment: That was 100% the problem. I updated and it's fixed now. Thanks!